# Image not loading when deployed on Heroku

Tags: html, css, heroku

I have deployed a full stack application on Heroku. The app has a few images which load perfectly during test, but once when deployed on Heroku, they fail to load.

What is the reason for the same?
Do I need to modify the HTML or CSS code?

For reference, this is the way I am referring to the image in HTML:

```
<img src="images/student.png" alt="Student" class="student">
```

Should I modify this line?

Comment: Please use the developer tools of your browser to get more information about the error. (See: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me a while ago. My images had an uppercase extension like `student.PNG` but I wrote them in HTML as `student.png`. It worked locally but not on a server. Check to see if this is your case. If so change the extension in lowercase or link them in HTML using the uppercase extension.